# Changing table values using php input

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am making a calendar using html tables and filling the input using jquery.
But it's not working and nothing gets populated in the table. Empty table is only displayed even after pressing the button.

Here is the code, plz point out where I am wrong:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$inputMonth = date('Y-m-d');

$totalday = date("t", strtotime($inputMonth)); 
$month = date("m" , strtotime($inputMonth));
$year = date("Y" , strtotime($inputMonth));
$getdate = getdate(mktime(null, null, null, $month, 1, $year));
$first_day = $getdate["weekday"];   
$day_of_week = date('N', strtotime($first_day));        
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calendar Test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("button").click(function() {
                    var firstDayNumber = <? php echo $day_of_week; ?> ;
                    var noDays = <? php echo $totalday; ?> ;
                    var currentMonth = <? php echo $month; ?>
                    var i = 1;
                    $("caption").html(currentMonth);

                    $('table tr').each(function() {
                        var $row = $(this);
                        $row.children().each(function() {

                            var $cell = $(this);

                            if (i >= firstDayNumber && i <= noDays) {
                                $cell.html(i);
                            } else {
                                $cell.addClass("closed");
                            }

                            ++i;
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            table {
                position: relative;
                border: 1px solid black;
                height: auto;
                width: auto;
                table-layout: fixed;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            td {
                display: inline;
                border: 1px solid black;
                position: static;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 1.5em;
                padding: 12px 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="tbl">
            <caption style="font-size: 1.7em"></caption>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <th>MON</th>
                <th>TUE</th>
                <th>WED</th>
                <th>THU</th>
                <th>FRI</th>
                <th>SAT</th>
                <th>SUN</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button>Generate</button>
    </body>
```

Comment: There's many things wrong with your code starting with the php inside the JavaScript. You can't echo your php variables or use them as simply as you're trying to do here. Try to create the variables you need inside your JavaScript. (This is only the first step to debug your code)

Comment: close ur php tag when html opens. In the line no 23 `code` var currentMonth = <?php echo $month;?>; `code` and then debug ur code

Comment: thats just a typing mistake ..forgot to put closing tag..still not working..

Comment: `caption` and `br` cannot be a child of `table`, move them outside

Answer (score 0):

Hey your code had few syntax errors (on lines 21, 22 and 23 [PHP Syntax Errors]). Then there was a javascript syntax error on line 23.
Corrected code is given below.

```
    <?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

    $inputMonth = date('Y-m-d');

    $totalday = date("t", strtotime($inputMonth)); 
    $month = date("m" , strtotime($inputMonth));
    $year = date("Y" , strtotime($inputMonth));
    $getdate = getdate(mktime(null, null, null, $month, 1, $year));
    $first_day = $getdate["weekday"];   
    $day_of_week = date('N', strtotime($first_day));        
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Calendar Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                var firstDayNumber = <?php echo $day_of_week; ?> ;
                var noDays = <?php echo $totalday; ?> ;
                var currentMonth = <?php echo $month; ?>;
                var i = 1;
                $("caption").html(currentMonth);

                $('table tr').each(function() {
                    var $row = $(this);
                    $row.children().each(function() {

                        var $cell = $(this);

                        if (i >= firstDayNumber && i <= noDays) {
                            $cell.html(i);
                        } else {
                            $cell.addClass("closed");
                        }

                        ++i;
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        table {
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: auto;
            width: auto;
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        td {
            display: inline;
            border: 1px solid black;
            position: static;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            padding: 12px 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="tbl">
        <caption style="font-size: 1.7em"></caption>
        <br>
        <tr>
            <th>MON</th>
            <th>TUE</th>
            <th>WED</th>
            <th>THU</th>
            <th>FRI</th>
            <th>SAT</th>
            <th>SUN</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button>Generate</button>
</body>
```